# transform the first value into np.nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
id    name  status v1.   output
123    John   a      2     NA
553    John   b      5     3
653    John   c      2     0
232    Wang   b      3     NA
324    Wang   a      4     1
424    Cici   a      1     NA
```

I am trying to calculate the difference between same name, under different group.

1. I need to calculate the difference between john b to john a, then john c to john a. The output should look like above

My code is:

```
df['output'] = df['v1'] - df.groupby(['name', 'status])['v1'].transform('first')
```

However, I don't want the first value to be 0, I want it to be NAN, is there anyway I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `where` with `duplicated` at the end

```
df['output'] = (df['v1.'] - df.groupby(['name'])['v1.'].transform('first')).where(df.name.duplicated())
df
Out[91]: 
    id  name status  v1.  output
0  123  John      a    2     NaN
1  553  John      b    5     3.0
2  653  John      c    2     0.0
3  232  Wang      b    3     NaN
4  324  Wang      a    4     1.0
5  424  Cici      a    1     NaN
```